# React native Firebase v6 Dynamic Link error. 400: Cannot shorten a short Dynamic Link

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I am trying to create a short dynamic link from within react native firebase.

I have already added the desired link on the firebase console.
I am trying to use the dynamic links library to create a short link on the phone:

```
const link = await dynamicLinks()
.buildShortLink(
  {
    link: 'https://abc.(com)/welcomeShared?invitedBy=1234',
    domainUriPrefix: 'https://abc.page.link/welcomeShared',
    social: {
      descriptionText: 'test description',
      title: 'Download with my link!',
    },
  },
  'DEFAULT',
)
```

my imports:

```
import dynamicLinks from '@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links';
```

I am able to create a normal link (.buildLink), but when i attempt to create the shortened one i get this error:

```
[Error: [dynamicLinks/build-failed] com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 400: Cannot shorten a short Dynamic Link: https://abc.page.link/welcomeShared?sd=test%20description&st=GET%20WITH%20MY%20LINK!&link=https%3A%2F%2Fabc.co%2FwelcomeShared%3FinvitedBy%1234[https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest#create_a_short_link_from_parameters]]
```

I have only found one case of the error but on the previous version of react-native-firebase:

[Firebase Dynamic Link Cannot shorten a short Dynamic Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54249622/firebase-dynamic-link-cannot-shorten-a-short-dynamic-link)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Did you solved this issue? Can you tell me how? I'm facing same kind of error

Comment: @George did you find any answer?